# do they sometimes omit the /d/ , /t/ sounds of the -ed ending?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, phonetics, connected-speech, consonant-clusters

In the phrase CCTV, closed circuit television; do we omit the -ed, and just say /kləʊz-sərkət-.../ in fast, connected speech. And, about the word "closed" itself, is it finished with an /zd/ or /st/ sound, when it comes alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final -ed would be either omitted or reduced to a vestigial -t in normal speech. The elision between the /z/ and the /s/ can clearly be seen in this spectrum, where the vestigial t can (believe it or not) still be heard.

[image]

I believe that the technical term for this is an **unreleased consonant**: you can find more about it [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/60776/unreleased-final-consonant-sounds?rq=1).

In normal speech, the word is pronounced /kləʊzd/, as can be seen in this spectrum:

[image]

Comment: "The elision of the /z/ and the /s/" ← Did you mean to write something like "the elision **between** the /z/ and the /s/"?

Comment: @snailplane, see this definition: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/elision I was thinking of definition 2: I can see that you are thinking of definition 1. You are probably right given that the context is phonetics.

Comment: @JavaLatte Hi. where did you get these spectrums?

Answer (score 0):

In fast speech it certainly could be elided in the way you mention.

If pronounced correctly, it would have the /zd/ sound at the end. We don't have final obstruent devoicing in English.

Comment: We don't have phonological final obstruent devoicing, but we do have phonetic final obstruent devoicing :-)

Comment: I respectfully disagree

Comment: [See here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/288730/unvoiced-d%ca%92-and-%ca%92-in-word-final-position/288765#288765), for example. Or [here](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/fortis-and-lenis.html). Or [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=iWFYJGFevG8C&pg=PA109&lpg=PA109&dq=final+obstruent+devoicing+English&source=bl&ots=4al2gyvFta&sig=mtV1MxVJI4ZF2WkfXvGERRHXt_E&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiuhpavm9jQAhVbFMAKHZKSCHg4FBDoAQgxMAQ#v=onepage&q=final%20obstruent%20devoicing%20English&f=false).

Comment: Oh, here we go. This is a nice simple page from the [Speech Internet Dictionary](http://blogjam.name/sid/?page_id=1526). :-)

Comment: @Araucaria Hi, I don't really understand the difference between 'phonological' and 'phonetic' in your statement. 'Phonetic' relates to the spoken language that people actually use in everyday life, 'phonological' relates to the standard speech sounds in theory, is that what u mean? And, by the way, where are u from?

Comment: @Araucaria P.S i know the verbs like 'close', 'raise' , when they stand alone , end with a /z/. But, i have heard many times 'closed' and 'raised' pronounced with /st/ at the end, that's why i asked

Comment: @glacier1500 Sorry, don't know why I missed your comments :( So, in some languages a consonant will change from an voiced phoneme to an unvoiced phoneme when it appears at the end of a word. So for example, in German words that end with an orthographic D are pronounced with a /t/, but if we stick suffixes onto the end of the word it will be pronounced with a /d/. In English this does not happen. However, we do find that consonants at the ends of words tend to be devoiced when next to silence or unvoiced sounds. However, a devoiced /d/ is still a /d/ and not a /t/. There are other important ...

Comment: ... aspects of the /d/ which remain /d/-like and not /t/-like, even though the /d/ has become devoiced. It is not a /t/!